# Access ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper from class defined in /lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionviewhelper

I have an `EmailHelper` class defined in `/lib/email_helper.rb`. the class can be used directly by a controller or a background job. It looks something like this:

```
class EmailHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

    def self.send_email(email_name, record)
        # Figure out which email to send and send it
        time = time_ago_in_words(Time.current + 7.days)
        # Do some more stuff
    end
end
```

When `time_ago_in_words` is called, the task fails with the following error:

```
undefined method `time_ago_in_words' for EmailHelper
```

How can I access the `time_ago_in_words` helper method from the context of my `EmailHelper` class? Note that I've already included the relevant module.

I've also tried calling `helper.time_ago_in_words` and `ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper.time_ago_in_words` to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby's `include` is adding `ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper` to your class **instance**.

But your method is a **class method** (`self.send_email`). So, you can replace `include` with `extend`, and call it with `self` , like this:

```
class EmailHelper
    extend ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

    def self.send_email(email_name, record)
        # Figure out which email to send and send it
        time = self.time_ago_in_words(Time.current + 7.days)

        # Do some more stuff
    end
end
```

That's the difference between `include` and `extend`.

**Or...**

you can call `ApplicationController.helpers`, like this:

```
class EmailHelper

    def self.send_email(email_name, record)
        # Figure out which email to send and send it
        time = ApplicationController.helpers.time_ago_in_words(Time.current + 7.days)

        # Do some more stuff
    end
end
```

Comment: That makes complete sense now. I overlooked the fact that I was trying to use `time_ago_in_words` within a class method when I normally have used it elsewhere in instance methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to include this on the fly:

```
date_helpers = Class.new {include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper}.new
time_ago = date_helpers.time_ago_in_words(some_date_time)
```